# What lessons (and mini-lessons) are available in Art Academy: Second Semester?

Tags: art-academy-second-semester

I currently own *Art Academy: First Semester* for the Nintendo DSi. As a hobby artist with a tenuous grasp of the basics of blocking, light, shadow, shading, and detail, the title did me a world of good -- so much so that I'm interested in picking up *Second Semester*.

However, [according to reviews](http://dsiware.nintendolife.com/reviews/2009/10/art_academy_second_semester_dsiware), the second title is a near carbon copy of the first game with significantly curtailed content, making me reluctant to pick it up without knowing exactly which lessons and concepts are covered. Because this is a self-graded title based on the player's own internal critique, walkthroughs in the traditional sense don't seem to exist from my cursory searches through Google.

So, a simple question: *what lessons and artistic concepts does* Art Academy: Second Semester *cover? Additionally, what subjects are covered in this title's "mini-lessons" for further study?*

---

*(Note that answers pertaining to the box release of* Art Academy *also apply, since this version is a straight compilation of both semesters [at a higher MSRP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003UVA4KC), with the addition of 80 "motifs" to use as reference material.*

*Since there's no chance I'll purchase this version of the game, though, a bonus question for the comments: what do they mean by "motifs," exactly?)*

Comment: Motifs must refer to the selection of Reference Images available in Free Paint mode.  There are 9 categories such as "Cats and Dogs", each with about a dozen images.

Comment: Indeed it does. I can confirm as much from my own copy, which I caved into buying some time after writing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box / card version of Art Academy contains the following lessons:

- Lesson 1: Tutorial (Draw a circle with the pencil.)
- Lesson 2: Tutorial (Blue lines with the paint brushes.)
- Lesson 3: Tree (Pen and pencil combined)
- Lesson 4: Pear (In-depth pencil and lighting techniques) [Minilesson: Pepper]
- Lesson 5: Lime (Moving from large areas to details with the brushes) [Minilesson: Apple and Peach]
- Lesson 6: Wave (Wet brushes) [Minilessons: Dolphin, Seascape]
- Lesson 7: Yellow Lilly (Color theory, Expressionist techniques) [Minilesson: Pink Lilly]
- Lesson 8: Puppy (Handling eyes and dark areas) [Minilesson: Cat]
- Lesson 9: Swan (Advanced color, Impressionist techniques) [Minilessons: Rooster, Goose]
- Lesson 10: Landscape (Use all previous skills, aerial perspective) [Minilessons: Mountain, Riverbank]

If the box version of Art Academy contains both Semester 1 and 2, then Semester 2 must include whatever's in the list above, but not in Semester 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I eventually caved into the temptation to buy the boxed copy, though I have yet to complete it (shame on me). :)

Comment: I found a boxed Art Academy a while ago, and have found it quite useful.  I have just finished, so I figured I'd write up an answer.